# Find the length of Longest Substring Without Repeating Characters in c++ using the sliding window algorithm and linked list. (leetcode)

Tags: c++, linked-list

See the question here https://leetcode.com/problems/longest-substring-without-repeating-characters/
I have seen many solutions to this problem in other programming languages than c++.

I was trying to solve it in O(n) time complexity using sliding window algorithm using a linked list, but the compiler is giving a very absurd memory error. Can someone explain, what I am doing wrong here?

```
/*struct ListNode{
public:
char val;
ListNode* next;
ListNode(char x):val(x),next(NULL) {}
};*/
class Solution {
public:
int lengthOfLongestSubstring(string s) {
    int maxLength=1;
    int n=s.size();
    int start=0,end=0;
    ListNode* head=new ListNode(s[0]);
    while(start<n&&end<n-1)
    {    cout<<1;
        if(search(s[++end], head)==false)
        {   cout<<2;
            maxLength++;
            add(s[end], head);
        }
        else if(search(s[++end], head)==true)
        {   cout<<3;
            head=del(head);
            start++;
        }
       cout<<4;
    }
         cout<<5;
         return maxLength;

}
bool search(char c, ListNode* head)
{   ListNode* l=head;
    while(l!=NULL)
    {if((l->val)==c)
        { delete l;
          return true;
        }
     l=l->next;
     }
    delete l;
    return false;
}
void add(char c, ListNode* head)
{   ListNode*l =head;
    while(l->next!=NULL)
        l=l->next;
    l->next=new ListNode(c);
    delete l;
}
ListNode* del(ListNode* head)
{
    ListNode* l=head;
    head=head->next;
    delete l;
    return head;
}

};
```

I was expecting the right answer to the test case instead of this error.
 The stdout that I got is : 1241
    ==29==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: heap-use-after-free on address 
    0x602000000010 at pc 0x0000004074e6 bp 0x7ffd60602ce0 sp 0x7ffd60602cd8
    READ of size 4 at 0x602000000010 thread T0
    #1 0x7fd2003452e0 in __libc_start_main (/lib/x86_64-linux- 
    gnu/libc.so.6+0x202e0)

```
0x602000000010 is located 0 bytes inside of 16-byte region 
[0x602000000010,0x602000000020)
freed by thread T0 here:
#0 0x7fd201d6c0d8 in operator delete(void*, unsigned long) 
(/usr/local/lib64/libasan.so.5+0xeb0d8)
#2 0x7fd2003452e0 in __libc_start_main (/lib/x86_64-linux- 
gnu/libc.so.6+0x202e0)

previously allocated by thread T0 here:
#0 0x7fd201d6ace0 in operator new(unsigned long) 
(/usr/local/lib64/libasan.so.5+0xe9ce0)
#2 0x7fd2003452e0 in __libc_start_main (/lib/x86_64-linux- 
gnu/libc.so.6+0x202e0)

Shadow bytes around the buggy address:
0x0c047fff7fb0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
0x0c047fff7fc0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
0x0c047fff7fd0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
0x0c047fff7fe0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
0x0c047fff7ff0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
=>0x0c047fff8000: fa fa[fd]fd fa fa 00 00 fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
0x0c047fff8010: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
0x0c047fff8020: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
0x0c047fff8030: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
0x0c047fff8040: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
0x0c047fff8050: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
Shadow byte legend (one shadow byte represents 8 application bytes):
Addressable:           00
Partially addressable: 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 
Heap left redzone:       fa
Freed heap region:       fd
Stack left redzone:      f1
Stack mid redzone:       f2
Stack right redzone:     f3
Stack after return:      f5
Stack use after scope:   f8
Global redzone:          f9
Global init order:       f6
Poisoned by user:        f7
Container overflow:      fc
Array cookie:            ac
Intra object redzone:    bb
ASan internal:           fe
Left alloca redzone:     ca
Right alloca redzone:    cb
==29==ABORTING
```

Comment: I'd suggest avoid using raw pointers. With new/delete there is just so much that can go wrong. Just don't.

Comment: I'd also avoid `using namespace std;` or is your variable `end` supposed to shadow `std::end`?

Comment: There is also `std::search`. Bad things happen, if it has the same signature as your function `search`.

Comment: The error is pretty clear: 'ERROR: AddressSanitizer: heap-use-after-free', which means *"don't use das pointer"* in german.